# Possible to bypass laptop inverter power source - HP dv5000 inverter 7 input pins?

Tags: power, lcd, laptop-repair, hp-pavilion, backlight

I've got an HP dv5000 laptop with a backlight that won't light up, (but is known to be good).  I've also got an inverter board which is good, but isn't getting power from the mobo.  So, my question is, would it be possible to bypass the original power source, and hack together some type of externally powered input just for the backlight?

If so, does anybody know the input voltage and meaning for the 7 input pins for the inverter board, or how to find out?

Comment: Some helpful info for this laptop on the HP site - Service Manual (PDF) : http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00700959.pdf